# Node Express thinks i am sending response multiple times?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webserver, middleware

So I am trying to program express middleware, and I am using return statements for every `res.json()` or `res.send()`, yet I am still receiving the error:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot remove headers after they are sent to the client
```

> My express middle-ware runs off objects, but they are converted down to their raw functions before the express server starts listening.

code:

```
// first contact for all routes
    _app.all("*", (req, res, next) => {
        if(next == null || next == undefined) return res.json(null);
        // Has user logged in?
        info("Connection from: ", req.header("x-forwarded-for") || req.socket.remoteAddress);
        if (!hauth(req)) {
            // they havent
            res.locals.authed = false;
            if (req.route.path == NEW_AUTH_ROUTE) {
                // get user credentials, validate, and create new session for user.
                const auth = newauth(req);
                // returns new auth key if user credentials are valid, 
                // otherwise an error prompting the user to login again.
                return res.json(auth == null ? ServerResponse.authFail : prepareResponsePayload(auth));
            }

            // tells the console that the guest user is unauthorized,
            // and passes false to the next() functions authed parameter, indicating
            // the custom route defined that the user is un-authed. Some pages such as
            // the profile page or account page will reject access instantly if this field is false.
            warning("Un-authed user with auth header of: ", req.headers[AUTH_HEADER_NAME] || "NONE");
        }
        else
        {
            res.statusCode = 200; // can be changed in next() function
            res.locals.authed = true;
        } 
        /**
         * -----------------
         * -   READ HERE   -
         * -----------------
         * 
         * All custom routes created in this file must return their json response.
         * The returned value can be anything, even null. It is good practice to be an object.
         * 
         * The next function from your route also contains a field in the res object specifying
         * if the user is authenticated or not:
         *  @see res.locals.authed
         * 
         * If your return value is an error, examples like on line 25 show how to properly use them.
         * 
         * @see ServerResponse houses static constants used for different responses. Includes errors.
         * @see ServerSideError An object wrapper for an error recieved from the server.
         * 
         * @see prepareResponsePayload prepareResponsePayload will prepare whatever is returned from next() to be sent back. Please read its contents.
         * 
         */
        res.json(prepareResponsePayload(next()));
    })

    // init routes
    for (const route of Object.values(routes)) {
        try {
            switch (route.method) {
                case "POST": {
                    _app.post(route.method, route.func);
                    break;
                }
                case "DELETE": {
                    _app.delete(route.method, route.func);
                    break;
                }
                case "ALL": {
                    _app.all(route.method, route.func);
                    break;
                }
                case "PUT": {
                    _app.put(route.method, route.func);
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    _app.get(route.method, route.func);
                    break;
                }
            }
            info("Registered route '" + route.route + "'. ");
        } catch (e) {
            fatal("Route could not be established. Name: " + route.route)
        }
    }

    _app.listen(SERVER_LISTEN_PORT, () => {
        info("Server Listening on " + SERVER_LISTEN_PORT + ".");
    })
```

> The comments are for my collaborators...

Here is where I define my routes:

```
/**
 * @type {Object.<string, Route>}
 */
module.exports.routes = {}

/**
 * Route for pinging the server. Mostly for testing.
 */
module.exports.routes.
    ping = new Route("GET", "/ping", async (req, res, next) => null); // all we are looking for is a ping, so no payload body is provided.

module.exports.routes.
    register = new Route("POST", "/register", async (req, res, next) => {
        try {

            info("Route...");

            const { username, email, password } = req;

            if (!vparams(username, email, password)) return new ServerSideError(1, "Please provide all required fields.");

            if (!vname(username)) return new ServerSideError(2, "Invalid Username.");

            if (!vemail(email)) return new ServerSideError(3, "Invalid Email.");

            if (!vpass(password)) return new ServerSideError(4, "Invalid Password.");

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                sql_addRow(new SQLRow({ username: username, password: password, email: email }, SQLTables.WEB_USERS),
                    (success, error) => {
                        if (error || !success) resolve(new ServerSideError(ServerSideError.ErrorCodes.OTHER, "Something unexpected happened."));

                        resolve(newauth(req));
                    });
            });

        } catch (e) { return new ServerSideError(-2, "Unexpected Error."); }
    });
```

When I run a `postman` request for `/register`, I get this error. Should i be seeing something else? I have reviewed my code and seen other forums but they are all saying I'm sending 2+ responses, but I cant see that here. Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This, by itself:

```
res.json(prepareResponsePayload(next()));
```

is a problem. You are both sending a response AND calling `next()` which will lead to other routes handling this request causing a duplicate response to be sent (and thus the warning).

If you send a response, DON'T call `next()`.

But, there's something else wrong in the `_app.all()` handler too and I don't really understand what you're trying to do there to know what to suggest to fix.  The core problem is that ALL possible code paths through your `if/else` logic need to either send a response or call `next()` and if they send a response, they need to either `return` or use some other way to make sure that no more code in the response handler runs and can also send a response or call `next()`.

Your first nested `if` that results in this:

```
return res.json(auth == null ? ServerResponse.authFail : prepareResponsePayload(auth));
```

is fine because you're sending a response and returning.  But, all other code paths are confused as you don't clearly do one or the other.  Perhaps you can just replace this:

```
res.json(prepareResponsePayload(next()));
```

with:

```
next()
```

But, I'm not really sure what you want all these code paths to do exactly and not sure what `prepareResponsePayload()` is supposed to do so you'll have to sort that out.

Summary: ALL possible code paths through your `if/else` logic need to either send a response or call `next()` and if they send a response, they need to either `return` or use some other way to make sure that no more code in the response handler runs that can send a response or call `next()`.  And, remember that the point of `next()` is to pass the request on to the rest of your request handlers (one of which will  send a response).